# How to use named regex groups in ack output?

Tags: regex, perl, ack

Suppose I have a foo.txt file with the following content:

```
[2010-11-13 12:00:02,656]
[2010-11-13 12:00:02,701]
[2010-11-13 12:00:02,902]
```

When I `ack` for the date portion with the following, it works:

```
ack "(?P<foo>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})" foo.txt --output "\$1"

2010-11-13
2010-11-13
2010-11-13
```

But when I try to use `--output` with the named group "foo", I cannot get it to work:

```
ack "(?P<foo>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})" foo.txt --output "(?P=foo)"

(?=foo)
(?=foo)
(?=foo)
```

Any help is greatly appreciate it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Note: Using named regex groups is dependent on your underlying Perl.  Named regex groups were introduced in Perl 5.10, but if you're using ack with an older Perl (since ack works with Perl 5.8, too), then they won't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ack "(?P<foo>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})" foo.txt --output "\$+{foo}"
```

`(?P=foo)` only works *inside* the regular expression (it's the named equivalent of `\1`).  `$+{foo}` is the named equivalent of `$1`.

Also, with most shells, single quotes will help you avoid extra backslashes:

```
ack '(?P<foo>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})' foo.txt --output '$+{foo}'
```

Comment: That `P` part of `(?P<name>…)` is optional.  That is, a simple `(?<name>…)` is plenty.

Comment: Note: This answer does not work as of at least 2019. See https://github.com/beyondgrep/ack3/issues/284.