# How do I return a portion of a string with ack (or an equivalent)?

Tags: regex, ack, backreference

I have a line in a file that looks like this:

```
$db['foo']['database'] = 'bar';
```

I want to use ack or grep or something to return `bar` out of that string. So far I have:

```
ack '^\$db\['\''foo'\''\]\['\''database'\''\] = '\''([\w_]+)'\' $file
```

But don't know how to get it to spit out just the first backreference, instead of the whole line.

Comment: Never mind: this is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222727/how-to-use-named-regex-groups-in-ack-output

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `perl` can help:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <> ) {
        printf qq[%s\n], $1 if m/\A\$db\['foo'\]\['database'\]\s*=\s*'([^']+)'.*\Z/;
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
$db['foo']['database'] = 'bar';
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

With following output:

```
bar
```